# I will try to add attribute in core data at run time

Tags: ios, exception, attributes, entity

M try to add attribute in core data at run time.
but when i try to execute code it will return error like this: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Resgistration setProperties:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000a5400`
Please help me.

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Resgistration" inManagedObjectContext:context];

//NSManagedObject *object = [[NSManagedObject alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *attribute = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *attribute1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSAttributeDescription *nameAttribute = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
[nameAttribute setName:@"lastAdd"];
[nameAttribute setAttributeType:NSStringAttributeType];
[nameAttribute setOptional:NO];
[nameAttribute setIndexed:YES];
[attribute addObject:nameAttribute];
[entity setProperties:attribute];
NSManagedObjectModel *objectModel = nil;
[attribute1 addObject:entity];
[objectModel setEntities:attribute1];
```

Comment: The exception message is clear - Your `Registration` class does not have a method called `setProperties`

Comment: Thanks. For suggestion. i will try.